# How to change windows, ctrl and alt keys on a specific keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a MacBook with Windows on it for work. I used a program called KeyTweak to rebind the <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Windows</kbd> keys so they'd work like they do in Mac OS.

Whenever I plug in an external keyboard however, these keys are also rebound. Is it possible to fix this? I've already tried Microsoft layout creator but you can't rebind the windows, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys on that.

I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the similar issue after I upgraded to Mac OS X (Yosemite) on my Macbook. I've never used KeyTweak so can't help you with this. But if you want you can use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html) to deal with this problem. With Karbiner all you need to do is remap command to option and option to command for ONLY external keyboards and any non apple external device.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however I'm using windows 10 via bootcamp on my macbook. Sorry if this wasn't clear.